# How to specify expiration of cacheable resources?

Tags: cache

I'm trying to speed up a wordpress site -- this site: http://richardclunan.net

I'm following the observations here: http://gtmetrix.com/reports/richardclunan.net/9ps7Zc0j

The first item says: "The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources:"

How do I specify expirations for those things?

(I'm not very technically-minded, and likely won't know relevant terminology -- really appreciate baby-steps explanation if possible :)

Comment: I don't believe this question is **WordPress** specific, but is rather an **`.htaccess`** question.

Comment: i've reposted this in webmasters.

Comment: Only 3 of those files are actually within your control to do anything about anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the answer within the wordpress realm, your **best bet is to install [W3TC](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/)** and use that plugin to optimize your speed. Even with the default settings you'd already be gaining a lot. If you want to delve further you can keep tweaking the settings within the plugin. The next step to take would be setting up (with the help of the plugin) [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/).

I would not worry about speed optimization outside of anything this plugin can do. The only exception to this rule: if you are on a VPS or dedicated server you can further speed it up by employing [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) and [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/).